# According to Catholicism, can demons force or misguide you into receiving communion?

Tags: catholicism, communion, demons

I was listening to Father Rippergers  online sermon about communion. He said, the demons force to receive  communion even when you have not repented. He also said receiving communion if you have not repented will lead to more sin and that's what the demons want. I had believed that you can take communion only when it's the will of God. The holy ghost will guide you and let you receive communion. And Jesus had said " No one can come to me unless the Father who sent me draws them, and I will raise them up at the last day".
There are many children's who take communion, have they repented? Can demons force or misguide you into receiving communion?

Comment: Do not think this is a truth question. Exorcists have spoken about this subject. It will take some time to find a source.

Comment: Would you consider placing this question under the umbrella of catholicism and I might be able to source out a response for you.

Comment: I've tagged this under catholism.

Answer (score 2):

**According to Catholicism, can demons force or misguide you into receiving communion?**

The short answer is: **They may influence someone into doing so, but they can not force one to do so.**

No one (or demon for that matter) can force someone to commit sin. Sin must be freely done and not done during duress.

That said, the Devil and his satellites can influence man’s thoughts in order to tempt him to sin.

> The demons gather strategic intelligence as they tempt. They learn by experience, and are good students of fallen human nature. Therefore, they tempt us now in one way, now another, observing all the while until they get some result — or not. We see that Satan himself tempted Jesus three times with three distinct sins: gluttony, avarice, and pride. Like a veteran safe-cracker plying his trade, he keeps feeling us out until he makes us “crack.”
>
> **That said, demons cannot make us sin. They merely exercise persuasion. For this reason, they can be said to “cause” sin only indirectly.**
>
> Besides tempting us to sin, they also prompt us to make errors in judgment that are not sinful in themselves, but could lead others into occasions of sin. For instance, if someone in a position of authority makes an error in judgment, this can adversely affect those dependent on him and cause their downfall. This is one reason we should pray for those in authority, especially the Holy Father and the bishops.
>
> How do demons persuade? They have no access to our intellect or our free will. They simply cannot know our actual thoughts or move our volition. But our bodies, our passions (or emotions), and our internal senses — especially the sense memory and imagination — are all subject to the diabolical power.
>
> As Satan is called not only “the tempter” (Matt. 4:3), but also “a liar and the father thereof” (John 8:44), we know that his malefice includes lying deception. This goes for his fellow demons, too. Given what has been said of their power over the sense memory and imagination, they are capable of presenting images in our brains that we later make into ideas in our minds. From these ideas, we can form judgments that are false and reasonings that are erroneous. Thus does he turn against each other those who should be allies. Thus does he stir up enmities of all sorts. Thus does he bring marriages to ruin. - [The Demonic](https://catholicism.org/ad-rem-no-190.html)

Thus it is possible for Satan to influence someone into going to receive Holy Communion in the state of mortal sin, but he can not force someone to do it.

If in the state of grace, the last thing that the Devil wants is for such a Catholic to receive the Eucharist since this would be an occasion for that soul to increase in grace before God.

It should be known that if a possessed person received communion, the strength of the Demon is diminished until Our Lord is no longer present in the Eucharist. Satan and his allies abhor Our Lord Jesus Christ.

Comment: Is it right to receive communion, if you haven't repented ?

Comment: No, it is a sin, if in the state of mortal sin.

Answer (score 1):

No one can force you to sin, including demons, because sin requires free consent of the will.

Addressing "Whether the devil is directly the cause of man's sinning?" ([*Summa Theologica* I-II q. 80 a. 1](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS080.html#FSQ80A1THEP1) co.), St. Thomas Aquinas writes:

> Sin is an action: so that a thing can be directly the cause of sin, in the same way as anyone is directly the cause of an action; and this can only happen by moving that action's proper principle to act. Now the proper principle of a sinful action is the will, since **every sin is voluntary**. Consequently nothing can be directly the cause of sin, except that which can move the will to act.

and [*ibid.* q. 3](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS080.html#FSQ80A3THEP1) "Whether the devil can induce man to sin of necessity?" co.:

> The devil, by his own power, unless he be restrained by God, can compel anyone to do an act which, in its genus, is a sin; but he cannot bring about the necessity of sinning.

In other words, he cannot force one to choose to sin. He can, however, make sinning appealing so that one voluntarily chooses to sin.

Answer (score 1):

We see at Luke 22:3 that Satan  entered Judas Iscariot and prompted him to betray Jesus.

We later see at the Last Supper,  at John 13:26-27 :

"Jesus answered, “It is the one to whom I give this piece of bread when I have dipped it in the dish.” So when he had dipped the piece of bread, he gave it to Judas son of Simon Iscariot.   After he received the piece of bread, Satan entered into him."

In sum, Satan can tempt one to sin, whether one has just received the Holy Communion or not.

Strange enough, it was Judas Iscariot who first received Holy Communion , and it was not Jesus who dwelt in him !

Comment: That's a good point, but I think Judas actually left right before the Bread of Life discourse and therefore missed communion.

Comment: We can't know, because John does not narrate the Institution of the Eucharist .